# Django signal was not triggered after Apscheduler job updates Model record

Tags: django, django-signals, apscheduler

I have an Apscheduler job that updates the active field in my subscription model and sets it to False. I created a post_save signal that should be triggered when the subscription model is updated, but it doesn't work.
Here's my code.

--job.py--

```
from django.conf import settings
from subscription.models import AccountSubscription
from django.utils import timezone


def schedule_api():
    try:
        data = {'is_active':False}
        AccountSubscription.objects.filter(expiry_date__lte=timezone.now(), is_active=True).update(**data)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

-- signals.py--

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=AccountSubscription)
def post_save_user_subscription_expired(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """Notifies users of subscription expiration."""
    try:
        if not created:
            if not instance.is_active:
                print("Notified users")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        # context = {
        #     'status': 'error',
        #     'message': 'A subscription expiration notification error has occurred.'
        # }

        # raise exceptions.ParseError(context)
```

Please is there something that I am doing wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update method does not call the save method and does not trigger signals. Cause Django makes a direct SQL query

It is documented: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#update

The solution is to make a loop for updating each instance directly or move the notify business logic into a function and call it after your updating query.